# convert oracle SQL to JPQL using cast and max function

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpql

I have a sql like this:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(XX AS integer)) FROM TableA;
```

where `XX` is a `varchar2` and I want to convert it to JPQL.  I've tried:

```
SELECT FUNCTION('NVL', CAST(MAX(XX) NUMERIC(10,2)), '0') FROM TableA;
```

and

```
SELECT FUNCTION('NVL', FUNCTION('TO_NUMBER', MAX(XX)), '0') FROM TableA;
```

but it just keep popping exception. I think my syntax is right but just dont know what's the problem is. Can someone kindly provide some advice? Great thanks~~

Answer (score 0):

I think that `CAST` is part of the [EclipseLink Query Language](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/toplink/jpa-extensions-reference/jpql.htm#TLJPA603) (EQL) extension, but not part of core JPQL.  If you don't have support for EQL, then your query might not work.  One workaround would be to just run the following as a native query:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(XX AS integer)) FROM TableA;
```

Another possibility would be to change the `XX` column to a numeric type.  Since you have the need to do math with that column, it might make sense for it to be numeric.

Comment: but I also got a problem that I need to return 0 if the result is null, so I need to use nvl also...

Comment: @MaxNg With a native query, of course this is not a problem.  Or, just make `XX` numeric.  I think `COALESCE` is part of `JPQL`.

Comment: I'm afraid I msut use JPQL as following the company's standard, I just wonder the the JPQL should look like in this case

Comment: Max, what I'm saying is that your version of JPQL may not support this.  Best thing would probably be to make `XX` a numeric column in the database.  By the way, if `XX` is fixed width (i.e. padded to the left with zeroes at a fixed width) then you can just take `MAX` of the text and it should be correct.

Comment: sadly XX is not fixed width... and change in DB column is not an option this time.
I found another way which use
select A.x from A where A.b = ( select max(A.b) from A )
but I dont know how to write it in JPQL, tried many times still get error.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing an implicit convertion by adding 0

```
SELECT MAX(XX+0)) FROM TableA;
```